# forEach in forEach prints double result for else statement in nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loops, ejs

I have restaurant collections and food collections in mongodb databse. Restaurant have name, description, and menus. Food have name and description.
In restaurant show page, i want display menus every restaurant. If menu name same as food name, it has link to food show page.
The code like this

```
 <% restaurant.menus.forEach(function(menu) { %> 
      <% foods.forEach(function(food) { %>
           <% if(food.name == menu) { %>
               <p><a href="/foods/<%= food._id"><%= menu %></a></p>
            <% } else {%>
               <p>! <%= menu %></p>
            <%} %>
      <% }) %>     
  <% }) %>
```

The problem is it gives double result for else statement. Like this:
    Food 1 
 
    ! Food 2 
    ! Food 1 
    ! Food 2

Comment: Looks like foods is independent restaurant.menus. Can you show what is in restaurant.menus and foods

Comment: Actually use forEach in forEach will print double result. How to handle it?